# How to build single binary from few python files

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have few simple scripts in a single folder. Something like this:

```
prject_root/moduleA.py
prject_root/moduleB.py
prject_root/moduleC.py
prject_root/moduleD.py
prject_root/config.py
prject_root/run.py
```

So `run.py` imports them all, while each module imports the config file (and can be run on it's own). I want to create an executable that will mimic calling `python run.py` and will hold all the data of all the files imported by `run.py`. How would I do that with `pyinstaller` or similar system, the binary will be executed under `Linux` (Debian).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to have a binary that can be run even if the user doesn't have python and you don't mind your binary being relatively large, you could use the `freeze.py` program. `freeze.py` should come with your python installation, so locate it on your system, and then run:

```
python /your/path/to/freeze.py /your/path/to/project_root/run.py
```

This will package up all of your code, and the parts of python necessary to run your code into an executable, `run`, that you can then use and distribute.

A more detailed description of [freeze can be found here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Freeze).

Comment: I won't run the executable on machine without python. It would be an advantage if there is an option to exclude the interpreter from the binary.